# python3.2)append two element in a list(lists in a list)

Tags: list, python-3.x

If I have an input like this `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`
The output has to be ... `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`.

I know how to deal with if it's one element but not two.

```
x=[]
for number in numbers:
    x.append([number])
```

I'll appreciate your any help!

Comment: Also I want to convert from the output I want to curly brace. {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} And if it's possible can you give me advice to get an general code that not only work for two grouped but 3 grouped. [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]] Thank you!

Comment: A oneliner: ```list(zip(a[::2], a[1::2]))```. It's easy to make it generic by wrapping it into a function taking the window/group size and looping over the range of group.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
out = []
lst = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
for x in range(len(lst)):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        out.append([lst[x], lst[x+1]])
    else:
        continue
```

To use this, just set `lst` equal to whatever list of numbers you want. The final product is stored in `out`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this. This solution also works for list of odd length

```
def func(lst):
    res = []
    # Go through every 2nd value | 0, 2, 4, ...
    for i in range(0, len(lst), 2):
        # Append a slice of the list, + 2 to include the next value
        res.append(lst[i : i + 2])

    return res

# Output
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> func(lst)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> lst2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> func(lst2)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7]]
```

List comprehension solution

```
def func(lst):
    return [lst[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)]
```

Slicing is better in this case as you don't have to account for IndexError allowing it to work for odd length as well.

If you want you can also add another parameter to let you specify the desired number of inner elements.

```
def func(lst, size = 2): # default of 2 it none specified
    return [lst[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(lst), size)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a shorter way of doing what you want:

```
result = []
L = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
result = [[L[i], L[i + 1]] for i in range(0, len(L) - 1, 2)]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few hurdles in this problem. You want to iterate through the list without going past the end of the list and you need to deal with the case that list has an odd length. Here's one solution that works:

```
def foo(lst):
    result = [[x,y] for [x,y] in zip(lst[0::2], lst[1::2])]
    return result
```

In case this seems convoluted, let's break the code down.

- Index slicing:
  `lst[0::2]` iterates through `lst` by starting at the 0th element and proceeds in increments of 2. Similarly `lst[1::2]` iterates through starting at the 1st element (colloquially the second element) and continues in increments of 2.
  Example:

  ```
  >>> lst = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
  >>> print(lst[0::2])
  (1,3,5,7)
  >>> print(lst[1::2])
  (2,4,6)
  ```
- zip: `zip()` takes two lists (or any iterable object for that matter) and returns a list containing tuples. Example:

  ```
  >>> lst1 = (10,20,30, 40)
  >>> lst2 = (15,25,35)
  >>> prit(zip(lst1, lst2))
  [(10,15), (20,25), (30,35)]
  ```

  Notice that `zip(lst1, lst2)` has the nice property that if one of it's arguments is longer than the other, `zip()` stops zipping whenever the shortest iterable is out of items.
- List comprehension: python allows iteration quite generally. Consider the statement:

  ```
  >>> [[x,y] for [x,y] in zip(lst1,lst2)]
  ```

  The interior bit  "`for [x,y] in zip(lst1,lst2)`" says "iterate through all pairs of values in zip, and give their values to x and y". In the rest of the statement 
  "`[[x,y]  for [x,y] ...]`", it says "for each set of values x and y takes on, make a list [x,y] to be stored in a larger list". Once this statement executes, you have a list of lists, where the interior lists are all possible pairs for `zip(lst1,lst2)`

Answer (score 0):

Very Clear solution:

```
l = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
l = iter(l)
w = []
for i in l:
    sub = []
    sub.append(i)    
    sub.append(next(l))
    w.append(sub)    
print w
```

Comment: This doesn't work. At least for python 3 (haven't tried 2). It's also not clear, I don't really understand what you want to do.

Comment: This worked (tried on 2.6). Just try it !
next method is key in iterating over set . .

input : (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
output : [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

l = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
print l  
l = iter(l)
w = []
for i in l:
    sub = []
    sub.append(i)    
    sub.append(l.next())
    w.append(sub)      
print w

Comment: Well the tag is for python 3 so you need to change to `sub.append(next(l))`

Comment: ops sorry !
Fixed.
Thanks